# Why wrong subtotal when I adding coupon code on magento2?

Tags: magento2, coupon, magento-2.3

I did created a Coupon under "Cart Price Rule"

=========COUPON SETTINGS======================
Rule name: $20 Coupon
Websites :" Mai Website

Customer Groups : General

Uses per Coupon : 0
Uses per Customer: 1

Condetion

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
Subtotal  equals or greater than  19.8
```

## Actions
Apply : Fixed Amount Discount for Whole Cart
Discount Amount : 20

When I add my Coupon code on my Order
it showing

[image]
26.76 + 30 = 56.76 (subtotal+shipping)
56.76 - 20 = ?
Expected Result = 36.76
Actual Result = 35.36

```
Differance is = 1.4
```

Why this difference ? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by Magento cache, you can clear cache and re-run indexer, and don't forget to clear browser cache.

Comment: I think the real issue is tax calculating after the discount on the cart. So we are confusing before and after the cart price

Comment: That's right, so check what tax calculation modules you are using (if you use third-party modules) or you can try with Magento default tax calculator